# .htaccess redirect to subfolder problem

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess to redirect users from www.mysite.com or http://mysite.com to http://mysite.com/subfolder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/subfolder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works perfectly, but for some reason its redirecting to http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/ (I need to remove the www), the subfolder is just a regular Wordpress installation and it has the default .htaccess file, I tried adding the following:

```
# Redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

To remove the www from the url, but it gives me a bad redirect error, I'm really new with this .htaccess configuration so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you should not redirect the user if he/she is already redirected.

To achieve this, you'll need a `RewriteCond` to check whether you are already in the subfolder.

Example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
```

Comment: Hi, I made the changes and now it doesn't show me the redirect error, but it wont take the www off the url, I updated the post to how the htaccess file looks like now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `RewriteCond` part was intended for the **other** `RewriteRule`. Put it before `RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]`

Comment: I changed it but now it shows me the redirection error again, it's weird because if I remove all the redirect code from the second htaccess and leave only the wordpress stuff it adds the www to the address even though I'm redirecting to http://mysite.com/subfolder ..